# PHP Variable Scope Weird Trouble

Tags: php, scope

I was coding PHP when suddenly Im being confused with variable scopes.

If I do the loop like this ...

```
function foo()
{

    $ctr = 0;

    for ($i = 0 ; $i > 8 ; $i++)
    {

        $ctr = $ctr + 1;

    }

    return $ctr;

}
```

$ctr returns a 0.

But if I do the loop like this ...

```
function foo()
{
    $collections = //This has 7 counts;        

    $ctr = 0;

    foreach ($collections as $collection)
    {
         $ctr = $ctr + 1;
    }

    return $ctr;

}
```

CTR IS RETURNING 7!

So what's is the problem in the first loop?

Comment: In your first iteration you say: **0 > 8** -> `IF TRUE enter the loop ELSE don't run the loop`

Comment: Yes, maybe you meant `$i < 8`?

Comment: `$i` is **never** higher than 8 in your case, hence the if is getting "skipped". So yes, the problem is in the first loop, and it actually is that the condition you wanted is probably `$i < 8` instead.

Comment: Oh yeah! the loop is not being called at all! Thanks Guys! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop you are trying to do seems to be a bit wrong.

```
    for ($i = 0 ; $i > 8 ; $i++)
                  ^^^^^^
```

Means, Set $i to 0. For as long as $i is bigger than 8, do this loop then increment.

Since $i is set to 0, the condition is never met, so the loop is never executed.

Change $i > 8 to $i < 8.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i > 8 ; $i++)
              ^^^^^^
```

since the loop starts at `0`, you have `0 > 8`, which is false, and your loop terminates immediately. Remember, loops terminate when that 2nd argument becomes false. it has to be TRUE for the loop body to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the first loop might be hard to spot, I must say.

It's about the $i > 8, your code doesn't even enter the loop. Invert the operator, ($i = 0 ; $i < 8 ; $i++)

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks so much for this one, helped a lot :)